# javascript indexOf cannot check the same numbers in an array

Tags: javascript

```
var number = new Array();

number[1] = document.getElementById("num1");
number[1].addEventListener("change",function() { getNumbers(0); },false);
number[2] = document.getElementById("num2");
number[2].addEventListener("change",function() { getNumbers(1); },false);
number[3] = document.getElementById("num3");
number[3].addEventListener("change",function() { getNumbers(2); },false);
number[4] = document.getElementById("num4");
number[4].addEventListener("change",function() { getNumbers(3); },false);
number[5] = document.getElementById("num5");
number[5].addEventListener("change",function() { getNumbers(4); },false);
number[6] = document.getElementById("num6");
number[6].addEventListener("change",function() { getNumbers(5); },false);

function getNumbers(num) {
    myNumbers[num] = parseInt(number[num+1].value);
    if(!validNumber(myNumbers[num])) {
     number[num+1].value="";
     myNumbers[num]="";
    }
}
function checkNums(Lotto, num) {
      x=Lotto.indexOf(num);           
       if (x!=-1) {
       return true;
   }
  return false;
}

var myNumbers = new Array();

function validNumber(num) {
if(checkNums(myNumbers, myNumbers[num])) {
  alert("Number already chosen. Please enter a valid number between 1 and 45");
  return false;
}
```

When i input a number into the array it keep alert the message "Number already chosen. Please enter a valid number between 1 and 45".

I want to ask about if I input a number into myNumber[0],and I call the checkNums function, it will detect the number i input into the myNumber[0] is in the myNumber array already and keep alert the message?

Comment: you mean that you set myNumbers[0] = 10, then call the function again? It'll throw alert of course.

Comment: So how can i use the checkNum function to check the number already in the array without checking the number I input?

Comment: @TanYunShen: Check if the number is in the array *first* and then insert it *only if it isn't already there*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the number is already in the array *before* you insert it. So, for example:

```
function getNumbers(num) {
   var newNumber = parseInt(number[num+1].value, 10);  // Note: it might be worth 
                                                       // checking for NaN here as well
   if (myNumbers.indexOf(newNumber) != -1) {
       myNumbers[num] = newNumber;
   }
   else {
       alert("Number already chosen. Please enter a valid number between 1 and 45");
       number[num+1].value="";
   }
}
```